# Laravel return rendered html view without \r \n -- json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

I have a little weird problem with rendering a view and replacing it after the ajax call with another html section.

code looks like this:

// ajax - controller function

```
$view = view('renderedData', [

            'test' => $data['test'],
            'unicorn' => $data['unicorn'],
        ])->render();
        return json_encode($view);
```

//  my ajax:

```
function sendData() {
        var test= "test data"
        var dummy = "unicorn whatever" 
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "{{ route('ajaxRender') }}",
            data: {'test': test, 'dummy': dummy},
            success: function (data) {
                $('tbody').replaceWith(data)
            }
        }); //end of ajax
    }
```

renderedData.blade view html:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($data as $d)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $c->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $c->$date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $c->$height }}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

( no whitespaces or empty lines at all in the blade )

The response in console looks like this:

```
"<tbody>\r\n                <tr>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n        <\/tr>\r\n                                            <tr>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n            <td>mydata<\/td>\r\n        <\/tr>\r\n    <\/tbody>"
```

I'm replacing the old tbody section with the new one. How ever, my table gets filled with my data and those  "\r \n </td>" and I don't know why. Like you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Another thing I've found out in the web console is that the json html looks fine and the answer below do have those "\r \n ..."

I think there is a problem with the "return json_encode($view);" because if I try a "return $view" - I can see the html formated correctly.

[image]

Comment: // oh and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why you don't just return an array in your view?
return [
    'test' => $data['test'],
    'unicorn' => $data['unicorn'],
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `preg_replace` before after rendering the view:

```
   $view = view('renderedData', [

                'test' => $data['test'],
                'unicorn' => $data['unicorn'],
            ])->render();

   $view = trim(preg_replace('/\r\n/', ' ', $view));

   return json_encode($view);
```